# When going back to full width navigation menu dissapeared

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm building [my first real website](http://www.bibliotech.nl) with the knowledge I gained using this website.

When I reduce the width of my webpage to look at the mobileview and open/close my menu the navigation bar in full width is gone. Though it doesn't disturb me that much, I just want to know why it does that.

Link is above, if you need my code i'll put it in !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What output are you expecting? Since mobile view is concerned, it must be display:none property set to that element when its width is below 768px or 480px.

Comment: I found my solution i added  "display: inline-block !important; " to my 'ul li' element and it's fine now !